# How do I remove underlining of contact elements (address, telephone number, email, URL, etc.)?

Tags: iphone, ios

The excessive underlining ('underscore') disturbs the typographical look and 
I don't need the very fancy linking to maps, email, phone etc.

Or better still: How do I select when and where to use these features?

Answer (score -2):

UIDataDetectorTypes recognize phone numbers, links, and calendar events embedded within the contents of a UITextView. The dataDetectorTypes property can be set on your UITextView instance to selectively recognize all, non, or some of these data types. It can be set programatically or in InterfaceBuilder by clicking checkboxes for the data types you want to be recognized.